# Cassandra - How to make table for friend accept or not

Tags: cassandra

I want to make table like this,

```
CREATE TABLE friendInvite {
  user text,
  invitee text,
  accepted boolean
  PRIMARY(invitee, user)
}
```

and expected queries are

```
1. SELECT * FROM friendInvite WHERE invitee="me" and accepted=false
2. UPDATE friendInvite SET accepted=true WHERE invitee="me" and user="you"
```

I think the query #1 is not good at performance because of accepted condition.

How can i handle this on Cassandra?

I cannot imagine using secondary index for accepted. because it will be updated to true if invitee accepts the offer. Is it ok If i use secondary index for accepted column?

Comment: Which cassandra version is used ?

Comment: @GuillaumeS It is not fixed. whichever is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE friendInvites {
  user text,
  invitee text,
  PRIMARY(invitee, user)
}
```

This table holds open friend requests and serves your query #1:

```
1. SELECT * FROM friendInvite WHERE invitee="me"
```

Then i would create a second table, where you store the accepted friend requests:

```
CREATE TABLE acceptedRequests {
  user text,
  invitee text,
  PRIMARY(user, invitee)
}
```

When you accept a request, the entry has to be removed from *friendInvites* and inserted into *acceptedRequests*

Comment: Then, I think acceptedRequests table is not needed. just removing means accepted. But I think deleting row will make the indexing cost

Comment: Hmm, It could be spending not much cost for deleting. Because it is not kind of much frequent request. I don't know the possible range of deleting frequency.. What do you think?

Comment: It depends on what you want to archive. If you need to display the accepted requests, then you will need the table. Otherwise just delete the entry

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a `materialized view` that allow your first query to be executed without performance loss :

Your table :

```
CREATE TABLE friendInvite (
  user text,
  invitee text,
  accepted boolean
  PRIMARY KEY (invitee, user)
);
```

The materialized view :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW friendInviteByInviteeAndAccepted
AS
SELECT *
FROM friendInvite
WHERE invitee IS NOT NULL 
   AND user IS NOT NULL
   AND accepted IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ((invitee, accepted), user)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (user ASC);
```

You can perform updates on the first table `friendInvite` and you can read your datas from the materialized view. When you update datas in table, Cassandra will automaticly update the materialized view.

This feature is available in cassandra >= 3.0

Comment: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views
In "When not to use Materialized Views", Low cardinality data will create hotspots around the ring. I'm curious why do you think materialized view doesn't have performance loss.

Comment: Hum i didn't see this part. Ok so materialized view will create some problems. But instead of create a materialized view maybe you can create an another table with the same partition key as the materialized view like Alex Tbk solution. You have to maintain datas in two tables with this solution.